# SSH bookmark manager for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have used JellyfiSSH on Mac OSX which basically stores your ssh connection details so you can quickly open connections using the built in SSH client to various servers without having to type in all the details, is there are similar thing available for linux? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When running `ssh myalias` from the command line, you can use [a file named `config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) in your `~/.ssh` folder, or a file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Here, you can configure things such as which real host name, user name and keys to use. Like:

```
# Use the private key "my-private-key" when logging in to myhost.com
# On the command line, just type: ssh myalias
Host myalias
HostName myhost.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-private-key
User myname
```

If you're not using keys: I can see there's a `PasswordAuthentication` option too, but I doubt you can also set the password itself in that file.

Comment: Terminology: Normally, SSH only uses key pairs, not certificates. A certificate is a key pair + additional information such as subject and issuer. (I assume you aren't talking about the OpenSSH 5.6 certificates yet.)

Comment: If you are using passwords instead of public keys, you really should switch to public keys.  It's very, very nice!

Comment: You can use https://stormssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ as ssh connections and Rammina for RDP.

Answer (score 3):

Try Asbru Connection Manager https://github.com/asbru-cm/asbru-cm / https://www.asbru-cm.net/

Perfect for Ubuntu!! ;)

(note that Asbru is a fork of PAC Manager, which is now no longer maintained [1])

.

[1] https://github.com/perseo22/pacmanager/issues/57

Comment: I fully agree? This tool is very usefull to manager a lot of connection (from different kind).

Answer (score 2):

[Gnome Connection Manager](http://kuthulu.com/gcm/) is definately worth a try.
it offers some interesting features and is usable, though it's not quiet mature yet.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You can try to improve your answer, if you give some more details _what_ interesting features Gnome Connection Manager has.